# [Android]SQLite DB cannot be accessed from others activities than one

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing some issues with my SQLite Database. I have about 5activities in my application, but i can access to it from only one activity. 
On this activity, i can fully use my DB and do all i want to.

On other activities, i cannot use it. I get an empty DB.

Of course, i use the same code to access my DB, regardless of the activity.

I use a homemade class to access the DB, derivated from SQLiteOpenHelper, and another class to manipulate the first one. The DB is downloaded from an online server into the "/data/data/com.example.btc_pe/databases/" folder.

My first class, to access the DB.

```
public final class BtcDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{ 
    public BtcDb(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("BTC","Db created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+ TABLE_PRODUITS +";");
        //onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

And my manipulation class :

```
public final class DbHelper
{
    public static int version=1;
    private static final String nomDb="basesqlite.db";

    private int num_id=0;
    private int num_tension=1;
    private int num_typeRacc=2;
    private int num_nbCond=3;
    private int num_technique=4;
    private int num_typeConn=5;
    private int num_conn=6;
    private int num_desiConn=7;
    private int num_refProd=8;
    private int num_desiProd=9;
    private int num_diamMin=10;
    private int num_diamMax=11;
    private int num_section=12;
    private int num_diamConnMax1=13;
    private int num_diamConnMax2=14;
    private int num_diamConnMax3=15;
    private int num_diamConnMax4=16;
    private int num_diamConnMax5=17;

    private String tableProduits = "produit";

    private SQLiteDatabase bdd;
    private BtcDb btcDb1;

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        btcDb1=new BtcDb(context,nomDb,null,version);
    }

    public void open()
    {
        bdd=btcDb1.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    public void close()
    {
        bdd.close();
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase getBdd()
    {
        return bdd;
    }   

    public int getCountDb()
    {
        Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"+ tableProduits, null);

        return cursorToCount(c);
    }   

    public int cursorToCount(Cursor c)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i=c.getInt(0);

        return i;
    }
}
```

In my activity, I have to instanciate the DBHelper Class, which instanciate BtcDB. 
So all I should have to do is this :

```
DBHelper dbHelper1 = new DBHelper(this);
dbHelper1.open();
//Manipulation of the DB
int i=dbHelper1.getCountDB(); //In example...
Log.d("BTC","DB Count : "+i);
//Other manipulations of the DB.
dbHelper1.closer();
```

As i said, it works pretty well on one of my activities but not on the others.

I'm pretty lost here ^^".

Comment: Any error log ? Perhaps missing a space after `From` keyword ?

Comment: add your log cat error

Comment: Your `onCreate()` is empty (though you mention it's a downloaded db) and the `SELECT` has syntax error. It shouldn't work anywhere.

Comment: I don't have any error log :/.

About my SELECT syntaxe : i fixed it, i was the origin of the problem indeed. I don't know why it worked x).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So, in short, the problem came from my SQL syntaxe. Really frustrating thing when you see how many time i spent on it.

Thanks everyone for your time.